# Is it possible to show a splash screen to user after using the RNrestart.restart() command in React Native version 0.71? [iOS]

Tags: react-native

I want to show a splash screen to the user after calling rnrestart.restart().
Splash : react-native-splash-screen ( 3.3.0)
RNrestart : react-native-restart@0.0.24

In older versions of React, I could solve this problem by adding code to the AppDelegate.mm file. However, since the AppDelegate.mm file has changed, I am unable to display the splash screen after using the RNrestart.Restart() command.

I used to use these codes in old versions of React Native:

```
RCTRootView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"appname", nil);
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:nil];
UIViewController vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
UIView launchScreenView = vc.view;
launchScreenView.frame = self.window.bounds;
RCTRootView.loadingView = launchScreenView;
```

Is there anyone who can help with a solution for this problem?